# find out where this group a value

Tags: php, arrays, range

I also wonder how I can go about finding the array where $var is
Example $var = 150 the array is [2]

```
$var = 150 

$base[0] = 0; 
$base[1] = 60; 
$base[2] = 3600; 
$base[3] = 86400; 
$base[4] = 31536000;
```

is there any way without having to use several ´ifs´?

I am looking for the index of the first element in the array that is greater than $var

Comment: Is there a way you could restate your question?  I am very confused and would love to help

Comment: 150 is not in this array.

Comment: @LagMaster: if $var = 150, the limit is 3600, then $base[2]; if $var = 50 on this $base[1]... thanks

Comment: Is anyone else as confused as I am?  Sorry that didn't really help me.

Comment: `base` is an obscure name for an array that houses the number of seconds in various larger units of time. Also, I would expect `base[0]` to be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correct, you want to find the index of a value in the array that is greater than the specified element,

You can use a while loop;

```
$i = 0;
while(isset($base[$i]) && $base[$i] <= $var){$i++}
// $i may now contain the index of the first element greater than $var
```

Sometimes, there may not be a value in the array bigger than $var, so after getting the index $i, you need to check if the value is greater, then access it. Like:

```
if($base[$i] > $var) {...}
```

Comment: I like `array_search();` also creative use of while loop, I wouldn't have thought of this question that way :D

Comment: Thank you. Seems he want the first element greater than, array_search can't work

Comment: so I used array to define the boundary of each unit (second, minute, day, and year) ... I am available for other ideas

Comment: I've updated the answer @PapaCharlie, It should work now, try it

Comment: what's the error? Maybe there isn't a value in the array bigger than $var at some point, so after getting the index $i, you need to check if the value exist then access it. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK I am answering this question based of of David Knipe's comment

```
foreach ($base as $key => $value) {
    if ($var >== $value) {
        $finalkey = $key;
        break;
    }
}

echo $finalkey;
```

Comment: He's looking for the first element which is greater than or equal to 150.

Comment: but this is not an exact value, should be between $base